# Why does Java require a dead return statement after a fully-covered enum?

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

Even though it's impossible to get passed the switch statement, I am still required to include a return statement. Enums can't be extended so it's impossible to add or remove other values in the future.

Is this a bug in Java? If not, do you know why this is?

Here is an example to see what I mean:

```
public class Example{

    enum Day{
        Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
    }

    public static String getType(Day day, boolean weekendOff){

        switch(day){
            case Monday:
            case Tuesday:
            case Wednesday:
            case Thursday:
                return "work day";
            case Friday:
            case Saturday:
            case Sunday:
                if (weekendOff){
                    return "party day";
                }
                else {
                    return "work day";
                }
        }

        //this is the line I don't understand
        return "";


    }

     public static void main(String []args){

         getType(Day.Monday, false);

     }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because it's possible for new enum elements to be added in future. If your enum-using class doesn't get recompiled, then your code would no longer be correct. This heads off that possibility.

As everybody else has said, just add a `default` clause to deal with that case, probably by throwing an `AssertionError`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yep, incorporated your comment into my answer. Cheers!

Comment: So you're saying that even though the enum cannot be extended, it could be in another package or library which, when updated, could get larger, but not require code that uses the enum to be recompiled?

Comment: Right, adding elements (or methods) to an enum does not require recompilation of calling code. This allows forward compatibility, so that you could slot in a newer version of a library you're using and have it Just Work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (with a default) instead -

```
public static String getType(Day day, boolean weekendOff){
    switch(day){
        case Monday:
        case Tuesday:
        case Wednesday:
        case Thursday:
        case Friday:           // <-- not the weekend here.
            return "work day";
        default:
            if (weekendOff){
                return "party day";
            }
            else {
                return "work day";
            }
    }
}
```